# Format Number in AppMaker Number Field

Tags: google-app-maker

I have a problem on my app developed in Google AppMaker

I have big numbers like 109863453 showing in a table.

I want to format this to show as 1.098.634,53 but in appmaker this format is not possible.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Regards

Comment: Looks like your number format needs to be in non-US format, so is your App set up to your locale? If it is, go to your label text binding, click on custom, and there you should be able to see a choice for setting a number format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know 1.098.634,53 is a number representation for German locale (possible in many others as well).
 If you choose it in App Settings you can use it in a binding like this:

```
@properties.<yourBigNumber>#formatNumber('#,###.00')
```

Note that there will be an effect on other widgets as well, say your google map widget will be in German locale too.